# phoenix ecto like API when use unicode

Tags: unicode, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

There are some `player_data` in my table `player` where names are Chinese.
When I use `where ... like #{name}` it doesn't work in Chinese. But these sql
queries are working in phpMyAdmin client. I don't know the reason.

```
iex(1)> Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(GameRepo, "select name from player where name like '%de%'")
[debug] QUERY OK db=0.8ms
select name from player where name like '%de%' []
{:ok,
 %Mariaex.Result{columns: ["name"], command: :select, connection_id: nil,
  last_insert_id: nil, num_rows: 1, rows: [["冷面De仙女"]]}}
iex(2)>  Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(GameRepo, "select name from player where name like '%冷%'")
[debug] QUERY OK db=1.2ms queue=0.1ms
select name from player where name like '%冷%' []
{:ok,
 %Mariaex.Result{columns: ["name"], command: :select, connection_id: nil,
  last_insert_id: nil, num_rows: 0, rows: []}}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with MariaDB 10.1.16 on Mac OSX, ecto 2.0.4, and mariaex 0.7.7. What versions of MySQL/MariaDB, ecto, and mariaex are you on and on what OS?

Comment: mysql 5.5.44   ubuntu 14.04 mariaex 0.7.7. ecto 2.0.4.You mean you can select the right rows using the code above?